# Horizontal alignment of controls beside each other in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, alignment

I want to put 2 controls, one textbox and one dropdownlist side by side, with one space among them.
I wrote this code:

```
Every 
<input type="text" id="Text1" Style="display:inline; width:40px;" />
&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Minute" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Hour" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Day" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The problem is that the height of textbox and dropdownlist are not the same while being rendered. I tried setting equal height to both of them but it renders like dropdownlist has a padding-top of 2 px. No need to mention that both these controls are affected by styles that make them the same font size and family.

I want to know whether there is a correct solution for horizontal aligning of these controls, without playing with padding?